# Configure RabbitMQ in Amazon MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, rabbitmq, terraform-provider-aws

I have Created a RabbitMq broker with Terraform. and I want to configure it through CLI.
Based on Hashicorp documentation: Amazon MQ currently places limits on RabbitMQ brokers one of which is configuration blocks.

Whereas my broker is in a private subnet and I or ( my Jenkins agent ) don't have access to it outside of VPC, How can configure it?

Comment: Using CloudShell maybe?